# How to get the difference between two lines

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, select, time

thanks for help
I have the following table in PostgreSQL

[image: PostgresTable]

The columns are

```
ON = END - START
IDLE = START (LINE 2) - END (LINE 1)
```

I need calculate "idle" using select ... The idle value is obtained using the start of line 2 subtracted from the end of line 1, following the example, the idle value 00:25 is 09:25 - 09:00.

I'm not able to create a logic for this, or the code for calculate it.

Here is my select

```
    select st.id,
       st.tvd_unidade,
       st.tvd_pdv, 
       st.tvd_cupom,
       st.tvd_operador,
       min(st.tvd_data_hora) as start_at,
       max(en.tvd_data_hora) as end_at,
       max(en.tvd_data_hora) - min(st.tvd_data_hora) as produtivo
  from ger st 
 inner join ger en on st.tvd_unidade = en.tvd_unidade and st.tvd_pdv = en.tvd_pdv and st.tvd_cupom = en.tvd_cupom 
 where en.tvd_tipo_reg in ('FINN','FINn')
  and st.tvd_tipo_reg in ('INFN','INFn')
 group by 1
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried to use: Rownum, but my table os more Than 100.000 values, tried to use a "with" select but dont work

Comment: Use `Limit 10` at the end of your query so it only processes a few rows each time. Will make testing and playing around much faster. Or, copy some sample data into a new table to work on your query in.

Comment: Rather than say what you have tried, please post the query in the question, along with the actual results rather than just saying it doesn't work. Doesn't work could mean anything from syntax errors to query hanging to no results to wrong results. Using row_number and CTE (with query) sounds like the right track, as does the lag solution given as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Before you worry about the maths, you need to be able to see all the data you need on one row. To see data from other rows, you use windowing functions. In this case, you could use the lag windowing function to look at the previous row - something like this

```
Select start, end, lag(end) over (order by [your sort key]) as lastEnd
from table
order by [your sort key]
```

should give you the data you need. Once you're sure you've got the right data, then you can start doing the maths calculations for on and idle

Comment: My table have more Than 100.000 rows, one by one show the start And end time ... Tomorrow i test lag and return here.

Comment: i dont undestand the function LAG as help me... I changed my query to use LAG but the result is the same with no "LAG"

Comment: Lag is used to see the value on a previous row. If you're on row 10, Lag(end, 1) means select the value of the end column from row (10-1). I left just used lag(end) above because one is the default. However, you need to give it a sort order to work with (that's the "over (order by ???) part. For your use, the sort order needs to be the same as the order of your main query. Search for postgres lag function for more info and tutorials.